# Where I can find p2 repository containing OSGI CXF bundle for build with tycho?

Tags: maven, osgi, cxf, tycho, p2

Where I can find p2 repository containing OSGI CXF bundle for build with tycho? All I can find is how to get the CXF with maven dependencies.

Comment: Why not just make one??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that don't exists such repositories for Apache project bundles.
What you can do (the easiest way with tycho) is to consume such bundles as maven dependencies.

Another alternative (that I use myself) is to create your own P2 repository that will contain all external dependencies of your project. you just need to create some features projects that points to the bundles you wanted and add those features in a p2 repository project.
That dependencies p2 project should be built before build all other projects.